# Maven Enhancing / Exploding war file

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

first of all sorry if this is a stupid question, but i am quite new to the topic of Maven. So please correct me if i am doing something wrong or not best practise like

Currently I have following issue: 
I have an 3rd party application in several war-files which i would like to extend (this 3rd party party allows to extend the software with own individual implementation).

Therefore i have created a Maven Project where i added the required war-files as dependencies in my pom.xml

My assumption is:
I have to somehow unpack the war file and then have to add my new implementation to it and then have to compile everything and then have to repack everything into a new war.

Is that correct or not?
How would i do it?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The Maven War Plugin [supports overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) that allow you to do exactly what you desire.